# R sum of multiple rows with many variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some treatments (`A, B, C, D` etc.) with 4 conditions (`z, y, x, v` etc.) and the sum of times they were used for patients (rows).

Example:

```
treatments = tibble(treatment = rep(c("A","B","AB"), 4), 
       condition = rep(c("z","y","x","v"),3), 
       n_times_used = 10:21) %>% 
  arrange (treatment)
```

Sometimes there is also a combined treatment AB used.
I want to write a function which:
 1. Checks if combined treatment AB is present in the current dataset
 2. If yes, I want AB numbers to be added both to "A" and to "B" numbers, but only in respect to `condition`. When added, the AB should be removed from dataset

For example: Last month I had 100 patients treated with `Az` (treatment `A`, condition `z`), 150 patients with `Bz`, 40 patients with `Cz` and 70 patients with `ABz`. So the numbers I want in my summarised table are `Az = 170; Bz = 220, Cz = 40`.

I try to construct something like

```
treatments %>%
   {stopifnot(any(.$treatment == "AB", na.rm = T))} %>%
   group_by(condition) %>%
 mutate(n_times_used = if_else(treatment=="A", 
                        true = sum(n_times_used[which(.$treatment== "A")], n_times_used[which(.$treatment== "AB")]), 
                        false = n_times_used))
```

same with B + AB and then filter to remove the AB from the table. Still there are mistakes in the code...

UPDATE 1. Example with treatment `C`

I add another example because in the first one only treatments `A` and `B` were included. While if we have a treatment `C`, I dont need `AB` to be added to it.

```
treatments_ABC = tibble(treatment = rep(c("A","B","AB","C"), 3), 
                    condition = rep(c("z","y","x"), 4), 
                    n_times_used = round(abs(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 10, sd = 30)))) %>% 
  arrange (treatment)
```

UPDATE 2. Example with treatment `A` or `B` missing

```
treatments_BC = tibble(treatment = rep(c("B","AB","C"), 4), 
                       condition = rep(c("z","y","x","v"), 3), 
                       n_times_used = round(abs(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 10, sd = 30)))) %>% 
  arrange (treatment)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition

```
library(dplyr)
treatments %>% 
   group_by(condition) %>% 
   mutate(n_times_used = if("AB" %in% treatment) n_times_used + 
     n_times_used[treatment == "AB"] 
           else n_times_used) %>% 
   filter(treatment != "AB")
```

Here, we have to assume that there is a single "AB" for each 'condition' (as is showed in the example)

---

If we have other elements also in the 'treatment' and not to affect those, then we do an assignment based on excluding those elements

```
treatments_ABC %>%
    group_by(condition) %>%
    mutate(n_times_used = ifelse(treatment %in% c("A", "B", "AB") & 
         "AB" %in% treatment, 
             n_times_used + n_times_used[treatment == "AB"], 
              n_times_used)) %>% 
    filter(treatment != "AB")

library(data.table)
setDT(treatments_ABC)[treatment %chin% c("A", "B", "AB"), 
   n_times_used := n_times_used + n_times_used[treatment == "AB"], by = condition]
treatments_ABC[treatment != "AB"]
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that `if` can be used like this in the `mutate`. The problem is that if there are treatments `C` and `D`, the `AB` is also added to them. While I need `AB` added only to `A` and `B`, but not to `C` and `D`

Comment: @lim_lim Can you add an example to test it

Comment: I added Example 2 to the post

Comment: @lim-lim  Thank you for the example.  I updated the post

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks

Comment: There's one special case that makes things more difficult. When the treatments `A` and/or `B` are absent in the table and the `AB` is present. In this case, the `AB` can't be added, because `A` and/or `B` doesn't exist... Well, maybe its too complex for this question.

Comment: @lim-lim  In that case by logic, there won't be any addition because there is only one 'AB' per condition.  Did you meant that only one of 'A' or 'B' is present?

Comment: If you want to that condition, you need `ifelse(all(c("A", "AB" "B") %in% treatment) & treatment %in% c("A", "B", "AB") & "AB" %in% treatment, n_times_used + n_times_used[treatment == "AB"], n_times_used)`

Comment: Can you try `treatments_ABC %>%
     group_by(condition) %>%
    mutate(n_times_used = ifelse(all(c("A", "AB", "B") %in% treatment) & treatment %in% c("A", "B", "AB") & "AB" %in% treatment, n_times_used + n_times_used[treatment == "AB"], n_times_used))`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why do you keep the last line `& "AB" %in% treatment`? If I understand correctly, the first line `all(c("A", "AB", "B") %in% treatment` already checks the presence of `AB`

Comment: @lim-lim  Yeah, you are right.  I forgot to remove it